# When someone comments on your answer, do you get a notice?

Tags: support

Noob question. Do you get a notice or the comment on your answer remains unread unless you happen to come back by chance and find it.

Comment: Something other than the Stack Exchange inbox? Maybe check out http://stackapps.com/questions/6455/ You can also subscribe to your question via RSS (bottom right).

Comment: I see thanks :)

Comment: So, I made 1 question in this site and made 2 comments on the answer I received. If he doesn't answer is it because he didn't read them or he doesn't consider them comments worth answering?

Comment: Notifications are not 100% reliable and, like other means of communication, never guarantee that the other person actually reads the message. Even if they read it, but don't answer, nobody can read their mind as to why. Every user chooses what to spend their free time on, be that answering comments/questions, retagging, etc. If they don't answer a comment addressed to them, I wouldn't go as far as saying they don't consider the comment worth answering. Maybe they rather spend their time in a different way, maybe they don't know the answer, or maybe they hope some other user replies instead.

Comment: Thanks again =P

Comment: Have you seen the little number with red background coming up near "StackExchange" on the top left side of your screen?